# Watin 2.0 Version elementwithtag

Tags: c#, watin

I Need to find a whole HTML tag and text is there in given URL..Currently Im using

```
IE.ContainsText("Some Text");
```

Works Perfect when i give`IE.ContainsText("<b>Username</b>");` returns false.But Tag is in the Page.I Tried the ElementwithTag But for Version 2.0 is requires three parameters.

```
ElementWithTag(String Tagname,Wait.Constraints.Constraint,Params String[] InputType)
```

I See all examples in Net with Only Two parameter and How to Use this Property.?? & Find a tag and Text in url????

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
IE.ElementWithTag("b", Find.First());
```